# How to add entry points by plugin in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, dynamic-import

I am trying to add more entry points by some messages in my source codes so that I can build additional files I need without change webpack config frequently

> I want to use dynamicImport feature in my project, however, for some reason I can't use webpack's implementation

Here are actions I had be tring.

First, I writed a babel-plugin and tied it to babel-loader, which will add new entry info to a Object

Then, I tried to write a webpack plugin, when compilation.succeedModule hook emits, the plugin read new entry info from the Object and call complilation.addEntry.

> here are codes how I add entry

```
compilation.addEntry(
  this.context, 
  SingleEntryPlugin.createDependency(entry, name), 
  name,
  e => console.error(e)
);
```

But I got error "Cannot read property 'addChunk' of null", I think I may need another method to add new entry